# Delete a database record with fs.files and fs.chunks

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I run MongoDB instance with 900GB database. There are documents with files stored in fs.files and fs.chunks databases. How do I properly remove a certain entry from MongoDB database? I mean when I delete an entry from the database it will also remove related files from fs.files and fs.chunks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These entries were created by the [GridFS API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) which is supported by each MongoDB driver and used to store large files (great than 16MB) in a set of chunks. You should use the GridFS delete operation to delete all the chunks associated with a file. The example Python API is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).